# Replace NA values in a column with values from another df column if conditions are met

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I need to copy values from a column in one dataframe to a column in another if conditions are met.

Using the example below, if `ID` and `BirthDate` are the same in `df1` and `df2`, AND `Week2` is NA then copy the values from `Week2a` in `df2`.

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
BirthDate <- c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-03-04", "2022-04-05", "2022-06-03")
week2 <- c("Y","Y","NA","NA","Y")

df1 <- data.frame(ID, BirthDate, week2)
df1
  ID  BirthDate week2
1  1 2022-01-01     Y
2  2 2022-01-02     Y
3  3 2022-03-04    NA
4  4 2022-04-05    NA
5  5 2022-06-03     Y

ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
BirthDate <- c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-03-04", "2022-04-05", "2022-06-03")
week2a <- c("NA","NA","P","P","NA")
df2 <- data.frame(ID, BirthDate, week2a)
df2
  ID  BirthDate week2a
1  1 2022-01-01     NA
2  2 2022-01-02     NA
3  3 2022-03-04      P
4  4 2022-04-05      P
5  5 2022-06-03     NA
```

The desired output I would get is

```
  ID  BirthDate week2
1  1 2022-01-01     Y
2  2 2022-01-02     Y
3  3 2022-03-04     P
4  4 2022-04-05     P
5  5 2022-06-03     Y
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`dplyr::rows_patch()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows.html):

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  rows_patch(
    rename(df2, week2 = week2a),
    by = c("ID", "BirthDate")
  )
```

```
  ID  BirthDate week2
1  1 2022-01-01     Y
2  2 2022-01-02     Y
3  3 2022-03-04     P
4  4 2022-04-05     P
5  5 2022-06-03     Y
```

NB, I assumed your dataset has real `NA`s rather than character `"NA"`s like your example; if not you’d first have to convert them (e.g., using `tidyr::na_if(week2, "NA")`).

Answer (score 2):

With your data you can do something like this:

```r
df2[df2$week2a=="NA",]$week2a<-df1$week2[df1$week2!="NA"]

# > df2
#
#   ID  BirthDate week2a
#   1  1 2022-01-01      Y
#   2  2 2022-01-02      Y
#   3  3 2022-03-04      P
#   4  4 2022-04-05      P
#   5  5 2022-06-03      Y
```

If your data points are `NA` values then you can use `is.na` instead of the logical expressions

```r
df2[is.na(df2$week2a),]$week2a<-df1$week2[!is.na(df1$week2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

First join by `ID`, then replace character 'NA' with real NA (you could omit this line, if NA is not just character NA). Then use `coalesce`:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("week"), ~na_if(., "NA"))) %>% 
  mutate(week2 = coalesce(week2, week2a), .keep="unused")
```

```
    ID  BirthDate week2
1  1 2022-01-01     Y
2  2 2022-01-02     Y
3  3 2022-03-04     P
4  4 2022-04-05     P
5  5 2022-06-03     Y
```